# How do I enable wifi on my Lubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I am trying to figure out how to enable wifi on a Lubuntu because, when I connect it to Ethernet it works, but when I unplug the Ethernet cable, it does not recognize or connect to a wireless network.

The result to the command: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 is:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:04b5]
        Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
        Kernel modules: ssb
```

Also the result to, rfkill list all is:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_3g: Wireless WAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t. Enter each of the commands in turn. Press Enter after each. Note the result. Next, in your question above, click *edit* and add the results you noted. Save your changes. When we see and analyze the details, we will then be in a better position to propose a solution.

Comment: Maybe it is disabled in BIOS settings.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: During start process the components of your computer are analyzed. The BIOS of the compute is taking care of some parts and interfaces. In BIOS offen it is possible to disable some interfaces, e.g. Bluetooth or Wifi. To check it, please refer to your computer manual. Mostly you can enter the BIOS directly after power on, then press ESC or DEL key (depends on manufacturer) and check for further hints, how to get into BIOS.

Comment: I do not have the computer manual.